# Horizontal sliding jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, click

Basically, I currently have a slide down menu that displays links when you click the header.
I want this to change to a horizontal slide but my knowledge is currently only with HTML and CSS, in other words I'm not very good at jquery/javascript.

So yeh, here's an example (Click CATEGORIES) http://newsunken.tumblr.com/
I would like it so that when you click categories the categories slide from the left to the right and display like "CATEGORIES TEES JUMPERS HEADWEAR"
Sorry for the noob question!

```
$('#box').click(function()
{ 
$(this).animate({
    width: '350px'
  }, 300, function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
```

and

```
<div id="box" style="width:70px; height: 20px;overflow:hidden; border:1px solid black;">Categories Tees Jumpers Headwear Gift Vouchers</div>
```

here's the best thing i could come up with but isnt as sleek as the one on newsunken.tumblr.com

Comment: That page seems to slide the categories vertically, not horizontally

Comment: when do people finaly learn, that javascript is totally different to java...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script slides horizontally fine, just in case I am showing the whole page.  Please, pay attention to the document.ready function

```
<html>
<head>
<title>sliding</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
     $('#box').click(function()
    { 
        $(this).animate({width: '350px'}, 300, function() {
        // Animation complete.
        });
    });    
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="box" style="width:70px; height: 20px;overflow:hidden; border:1px solid black;">Categories Tees Jumpers Headwear Gift Vouchers</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: great, again as i'm not exactly great at this would you be able to tell me if there's a way to toggle it so if the user clicks it again itll revert to teh small box? i've tried to use the toggle function but having no luck

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it is what you are looking for, but try this:

```
$('#box').click(function()
{ 
$(this).animate({
    height: 'toggle',
    width: '350px'
  }, 300, function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
```